# Token limit in Jquery token input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, railscasts

This tokeninput is from   http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/
I see the tutorial from http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields-revised

As i am using it in many places i need sometime only one value selection while in others multiple values. It is the code for multiple value selction.
Now i want it to search only once and submit only one value.
Is there any way to code it in my coffescript file to select only one value and stop?

```
my code for customers.js.coffee
jQuery ->
  $('#customer_plan_tokens').tokenInput '/plans.json'
    theme: 'facebook'
    prePopulate: $('#customer_plan_tokens').data('load')

my code for _form.html.erb for cusomers is
   <div class="form-inputs-right">

            Projects: <%= f.text_field :plan_tokens, data: {load: @customer.plans}, :label => "Projects" %>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an option in JQueryToken input called as "tokenLimit"....You can set this value to 1 in places where you have to enter only one value. In the other places, you can set the value of token limits accordingly.

Please refer to : http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

Search for "tokenLimit" for more details. Hope this helps.

Comment: cant i pass the limit from my cofeescript code. I dont want to change the code inside tokens js.

Comment: You need to set the tokenLimit in order to restrict the number of tokens. Just assign the value and it will do the job for you.

Comment: any workin example. since i am using token gem i could not change js of token. So any working code that i can add manually later where i need this

Comment: Just add tokenLimit: 1 option to your Jquery tokenInput function call and it should work fine.